# WPF override property specified on element from style trigger

Tags: wpf

I have two TextBlock `Run` elements with different colors (one is explicitly set on the element). I want them both to change color to red when the value `Foo` is zero, using the same style. Is this possible somehow? I would rather not duplicate the Style. This is what I want to work:

```
<Style x:Key="ForegroundStyleTrigger" TargetType="Run">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Foo, Mode=OneWay}"
         Style="{StaticResource ForegroundStyleTrigger}"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Bar, Mode=OneWay}"
         Foreground="Blue"
         Style="{StaticResource ForegroundStyleTrigger}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

But since the locally defined color (the one defined on the element) takes precedence over style triggers, nothing happens and the text stays blue for that text run.

Question: Can I override a TextBlocks runs color from a style resource? 
If not, how can achieve the expected result without duplicating the style resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I override a TextBlocks runs color from a style resource?

No, you cannot override a local value using a style setter.

> If not, how can achieve the expected result without duplicating the style resource?

If you want the Foreground of the second Run element to be Blue by default and Red only if the Foo source property returns "0" you could create another style and base this one on your existing one:

```
    <Style x:Key="ForegroundStyleTrigger" TargetType="Run">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="BlueByDefault" BasedOn="{StaticResource ForegroundStyleTrigger}" TargetType="Run">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
    </Style>


    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{Binding Foo, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource ForegroundStyleTrigger}"/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Bar, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource BlueByDefault}"/>
    </TextBlock>
```

But you cannot set the Foreground property to a local value if you want your style setters to apply.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `Style` inheritance to achieve what you're asking. The trick then is that all properties must be in the `Style` as local explicitly set values override implicitly set `Style` values:

```
<Style x:Key="ForegroundStyleTrigger" TargetType="Run">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foo}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BlueForegroundStyleTrigger" BasedOn="{StaticResource ForegroundStyleTrigger}" TargetType="Run">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
</Style>


<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Foo, Mode=OneWay}"
         Style="{StaticResource ForegroundStyleTrigger}"/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Bar, Mode=OneWay}"
         Style="{StaticResource BlueForegroundStyleTrigger}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: This is also the correct answer, I just spent like 10 minutes deciding which one should be marked as correct. The other one was to me just slightly clearer. thank you anyway!

Comment: Thanks. I would however suggest you get used to the correct technical terms rather than the dumbed down language - bearing in mind the level of organisations primarily using WPF to develop with, you will be asked questions using this exact terminology when taking interviews with them.