# Foreground does not apply for labels

Tags: wpf, templates, styles

I have some labels like this:

```
 <Label x:Name="ledCalculate" Width="Auto" Content="Calculate" Height="25" FontFamily="Cambria" FontSize="18.667" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Padding="10,0,0,0"  BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Style="{StaticResource RightPanelLabels}" Grid.Row="11"/>
```

I defined a style for it:

```
 <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="RightPanelLabels" BasedOn="{StaticResource 
    {x:Type Label } }">

        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFEABEBE"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF818080"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

Border thickness setter in style applies for control and it has upper precedence in style, and visual studio ignores its values in local, but  foreground setter in style does not applies, when i set it locally it applies,

Why border thickness in style have upper precedence but foreground in local have upper precedence????????

I know there is a default template for labels like bellow that have a trigger for `IsEnabled` , that template is something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

Can anyone help me?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the local styles take precedence over defined styles, so inline styles will always override other styles defined in resources.
When I run the code I found that Style's `BorderThickness` also get overridden by the local inline style value for `BorderThickness` as well.

I too would love to hear if there's a workaround for this.
I found this article as well, hope it helps [Same problem with a style trigger though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41037706/wpf-override-property-specified-on-element-from-style-trigger)

EDIT:

Upon trying it few different ways I found using this method we can override the label's inline `Foreground` style, but I don't know whether it's the healthiest way

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                           Foreground="Red" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
  </Style>

 <Label FontSize="50" Foreground="Black"> I am Black inline, Red on Style </Label>
```

This is me just editing the `ContentTemplate` of the `Label` .
Basically, this possible for `Label` because `Label` derives from `ContentControl` whereas `TextBlock` lives in the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace, it is not a control. It derives directly from `FrameworkElement`.
`TextBlock` are used in many other controls to show texts, including in `Label`.

[image: Class Hierarchy for the 2 elements]

[Refer this article to know more about this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/wpf-textblock-vs-label1)

Comment: Great, it works, but i don't know what was  difference between foreground and border brush, thank's

Comment: `BorderBrush` property represents the brush that is used to draw the border, whereas `Foreground` (let's say of a `TextBlock`) is the color of text, and `Background` is the color of the background of the control, which is behind the `Foreground` of the element.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change property name in style setter

```
<Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="#FFEABEBE">
```